# error: message from Actor to Actor was not delivered.[1] dead letters encountered. Distributed pub-sub working across clusters not working

Tags: java, akka, publish-subscribe, actor, akka-remote-actor

I'm trying to make distributed pub-sub across different cluster system but it's not working whatever i try.

All I'm trying to do is create a simple example where.

1) I create a topic, say "content".

2) One node in say jvm A creates the topic, subscribes to it, and a publisher who publishes to it too.

3) In a different node , say jvm B on a different port , I create a subscriber.

4) When i sent a message to the topic from jvm A, then I want the subscriber on jvm B to receive it too as its subscribed to the same topic.

Any helps would be greatly appreciated or a simple working example of distributed pub sub with subscribers and publishers in different cluster system on different ports, in Java.

here is the code for app1 and its config file.

```
 public class App1{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("akka.remote.netty.tcp.port", "2551");
    ActorSystem clusterSystem = ActorSystem.create("ClusterSystem");
    ClusterClientReceptionist clusterClientReceptionist1 = ClusterClientReceptionist.get(clusterSystem);
    ActorRef subcriber1=clusterSystem.actorOf(Props.create(Subscriber.class), "subscriber1");
    clusterClientReceptionist1.registerSubscriber("content", subcriber1);
    ActorRef publisher1=clusterSystem.actorOf(Props.create(Publisher.class), "publisher1");
    clusterClientReceptionist1.registerSubscriber("content", publisher1);
    publisher1.tell("testMessage1", ActorRef.noSender());

    }
}
```

app1.confi

```
akka {
loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
loglevel = "DEBUG"
stdout-loglevel = "DEBUG"
logging-filter = "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter"
actor {
provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
}
remote {
log-remote-lifecycle-events = off
enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
netty.tcp {
  hostname = "127.0.0.1"
  port = 2551
  }
}
cluster {
seed-nodes = [
  "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2551"
]
auto-down-unreachable-after = 10s
}
akka.extensions = ["akka.cluster.pubsub.DistributedPubSub",
"akka.contrib.pattern.ClusterReceptionistExtension"]
  akka.cluster.pub-sub {
name = distributedPubSubMediator
role = ""
routing-logic = random
gossip-interval = 1s
removed-time-to-live = 120s
max-delta-elements = 3000
use-dispatcher = ""
}

akka.cluster.client.receptionist {
name = receptionist
role = ""
number-of-contacts = 3
response-tunnel-receive-timeout = 30s
use-dispatcher = ""
heartbeat-interval = 2s
acceptable-heartbeat-pause = 13s
failure-detection-interval = 2s
  }
}
```

code for app2 and its config file

```
public class App
{
   public static Set<ActorPath> initialContacts() {
   return new HashSet<ActorPath>(Arrays.asList(          
   ActorPaths.fromString("akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2551/system/receptionist")));
}

public static void main( String[] args ) {
    System.setProperty("akka.remote.netty.tcp.port", "2553");
    ActorSystem clusterSystem = ActorSystem.create("ClusterSystem2");
    ClusterClientReceptionist clusterClientReceptionist2 = ClusterClientReceptionist.get(clusterSystem);
    final ActorRef clusterClient = clusterSystem.actorOf(ClusterClient.props(ClusterClientSettings.create(
            clusterSystem).withInitialContacts(initialContacts())), "client"); 
    ActorRef subcriber2=clusterSystem.actorOf(Props.create(Subscriber.class), "subscriber2");
    clusterClientReceptionist2.registerSubscriber("content", subcriber2);
    ActorRef publisher2=clusterSystem.actorOf(Props.create(Publisher.class), "publisher2");
    publisher2.tell("testMessage2", ActorRef.noSender());
    clusterClient.tell(new ClusterClient.Send("/user/publisher1", "hello", true), null);

 }
}
```

app2.confi

```
    akka {
loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
loglevel = "DEBUG"
stdout-loglevel = "DEBUG"
logging-filter = "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter"
actor {
provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
}
remote {
log-remote-lifecycle-events = off
enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
netty.tcp {
  hostname = "127.0.0.1"
  port = 2553
  }
}
cluster {
seed-nodes = [
  "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2553"
]
auto-down-unreachable-after = 10s
}
akka.extensions = ["akka.cluster.pubsub.DistributedPubSub",
"akka.contrib.pattern.ClusterReceptionistExtension"]
  akka.cluster.pub-sub {
name = distributedPubSubMediator
role = ""
routing-logic = random
gossip-interval = 1s
removed-time-to-live = 120s
max-delta-elements = 3000
use-dispatcher = ""
}

akka.cluster.client.receptionist {
name = receptionist
role = ""
number-of-contacts = 3
response-tunnel-receive-timeout = 30s
use-dispatcher = ""
heartbeat-interval = 2s
acceptable-heartbeat-pause = 13s
failure-detection-interval = 2s
  }
}
```

Publisher and Subscriber class are same for both application which is given below.

Publisher:

```
 public class Publisher extends UntypedActor {
 private final ActorRef mediator =
        DistributedPubSub.get(getContext().system()).mediator();

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Object msg) throws Exception {
     if (msg instanceof String) {
         mediator.tell(new DistributedPubSubMediator.Publish("events", msg), getSelf());
    } else {
        unhandled(msg);
    }
 }

}
```

Subscriber:

```
public class Subscriber extends UntypedActor {
private final LoggingAdapter log = Logging.getLogger(getContext().system(), this);

public Subscriber(){

    ActorRef mediator = DistributedPubSub.get(getContext().system()).mediator();
    mediator.tell(new DistributedPubSubMediator.Subscribe("events", getSelf()), getSelf());

}

public void onReceive(Object msg) throws Throwable {
    if (msg instanceof String) {
        log.info("Got: {}", msg);
    } else if (msg instanceof DistributedPubSubMediator.SubscribeAck) {
        log.info("subscribing");
    } else {
        unhandled(msg);
    }
}
}
```

i got this error in receiver side app while running both apps.**Dead letters encounterd**

```
[ClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-21] INFO  akka.actor.RepointableActorRef - Message [java.lang.String] from Actor[akka://ClusterSystem/system/receptionist/akka.tcp%3A%2F%2FClusterSystem2%40127.0.0.1%3A2553%2FdeadLetters#188707926] to Actor[akka://ClusterSystem/system/distributedPubSubMediator#1119990682] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

and in sender side app message send successfully is displayed in log.

```
[ClusterSystem2-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-22] DEBUG akka.cluster.client.ClusterClient - Sending buffered messages to receptionist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the ClusterClient in that way does not really make sense and does not have anything to do with using the distributed pub sub, as both your nodes are a part of the cluster you can just use the distributed pub sub api directly.

Here is a simple main including config creating a two node cluster using your exact Publisher and Subscriber actors that works as expected:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  final Config config = ConfigFactory.parseString(
    "akka.actor.provider=cluster\n" +
    "akka.remote.netty.tcp.port=2551\n" +
    "akka.cluster.seed-nodes = [ \"akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2551\"]\n");

  ActorSystem node1 = ActorSystem.create("ClusterSystem", config);
  ActorSystem node2 = ActorSystem.create("ClusterSystem",
    ConfigFactory.parseString("akka.remote.netty.tcp.port=2552")
      .withFallback(config));

  // wait a bit for the cluster to form
  Thread.sleep(3000);

  ActorRef subscriber = node1.actorOf(
    Props.create(Subscriber.class),
    "subscriber");

  ActorRef publisher = node2.actorOf(
    Props.create(Publisher.class), 
    "publisher");

  // wait a bit for the subscription to be gossiped
  Thread.sleep(3000);

  publisher.tell("testMessage1", ActorRef.noSender());
}
```

Note that distributed pub sub does not give any guarantees of delivery, so if you send a message before the mediators has gotten in contact with each other, the message will simply be lost (hence the `Thread.sleep` statements, which are ofc not something you should do in actual code).

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that your actor systems have different names ClusterSystem and ClusterSystem2.  At least I was having the same issue because I had two different services in the cluster but I names the systems in each service with a different name.